# User defined routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

There is a lot of good information on routing in Rails.  I must be missing something, but I can't seem to find a good example of a Rails application that allows dynamically defined user specific routes.

For example, my application is hosted at:

```
www.thing.com
```

... and serves out user generated content.

I'd like to give the user an option to define a suffix that let's them share a somewhat customized URL to their content.  For example, if a user 'joe' generates some car info they might want to make it avilable via joescars at:

```
www.thing.com/joescars
```

Maybe later they decide they want to serve it out under 'carsbyjoe' at:

```
www.thing.com/carsbyjoe
```

I can handle limiting what suffixs are valid.  Is there a Rails way to codify this kind of dynamic routing?

Comment: Have you tried something like `get 'uri/:user_route' => 'custom_pages#custom_controller_method'`. You could then use the param[:user_route] for what you'd like in the controller.

Comment: just something to keep in mind, using a generic `/:uri` would be bad, because every single random url would hit your database, and every 404 would be tested against the database first, for me I would try limiting it to something like `/pages/:uri` for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to do this. In your `config/routes` file add a route that says `get '/:user_route' => 'somecontroller#someaction'`. You'll have to put it at the very bottom because routes are matched from top to bottom and this will match things like `/users` or other routes you'll likely want directed elsewhere.

Then, in your controller you can access `params[:user_route]` to show the appropriate content. There are a number of ways to store this custom content in your database, depending on your needs. You might have a model representing these custom routes like `CustomRoute.find_by_route(params[:user_route])`, or maybe each user will have a custom route so you could do `User.find_by_route(params[:user_route]).custom_page` and each `User` has one `custom_page`.